# Windows 7: Lan interface down when cable unplugged

Tags: windows-7, networking

I have a Win7 as Desktop environment (192.168.0.4) and a VMware Workstation with a Linux VM (192.168.0.5). Its all on the same laptop. The VM uses Bridged Network Adapter, directly connected to the network interfaces of Win7. In Win7 I can use Putty to connect to the Linux VM. Now the problem is if I unplug the cat5 cable from my laptop, the network interface goes down and putty looses the connection. How can I avoid that?

I the internet are hints that tell me I should set this Reg key, but after a Win7 restart, the behavior does not change.

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters\DisableDHCPMediaSense
>   = 1 (REG_DWORD)

Maybe a Host Only virtual VMware adapter instead of the bridged adapter would solve this issue. But if I understand the description correctly, the VM cannot use the internet.

Thanks

Peter

Comment: You are not restricted to a single network adapter per VM.

Comment: You mean creating a new virtual network adapter for connecting the VM to Win7 and the (sometimes available) internet connection?

Answer (score 0):

Use `NAT` instead of `Bridged` for the VM network adapter. It has no issues regarding the Internet access.

Also you could try to uncheck this check box in VM's settings

[image: VMware network adapter settings]